# UML Activity Diagram: show work results

Tags: uml

I would like to visualize input to and results of activities in UML activity diagrams, e.g. documents or files or information entities. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity Diagrams support Object Flows which should do the job.  See e.g. [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener on your objects model .

If I remember well one of customers ask me to highlight the name of component if this element was changed. The trick I did was to parse the model xml/xmi and detect changes.
This integration was possible and easy because the model of the UML tool that my customer was using was live synchronized with diagrams and saved as xmi format on the hard disk.